# Nivo-Slider disappears while slide is being changed in IE ≤ 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, nivo-slider

I'm testing the slider and it works in Chrome and IE 9+ but doesn't work properly in earlier versions.

The problem that occurs to me is that while the previous slide is rolled up, an error-like image is revealed (and the loading.gif is then visible) and remains for over two seconds, until the next slide appears.
I tried changing the animation type but the problem persists.

I applied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9154894/75500) answer and it didn't solve the issue.

Any clue?

I've posted same question at [dev7studios](http://goo.gl/hK6O4) as well, no answer however.

[image]

**Update**
This is the method that generates the images:

```
private static MvcHtmlString BuildImageTag(string blobName, object htmlAttributes = null, string name = null)
{
  TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("img");

  var src = BlobHelper.GetBlobUri(blobName);

  tag.Attributes.Add("src", src.ToString());
  tag.Attributes.Add("name", name);
  if (htmlAttributes != null)
    tag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), true);

  return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

How do I change it so that the closing tag is separate (as explain in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16038391/75500) answer)?

### Update 2

After enabling JS debugging, I see there is a debugger break at the nivo slider js file.

[image]

The line in the JS is:

```
u.attr("src",i.currentImage.attr("src")).show();
```

I'm not even sure it's related but I thought it might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the source code of your page, i see:

```
<img name="ImageFileName" src="https://levelblob.blob.core.windows.net/levelblob/images/slides/b0624213-f3cd-4e0f-b1ae-e5e97429b087.jpg" title=""></img>
```

This is not valid img tag as W3C specify:

> The  tag is empty, which means that it contains attributes only,
>   and has no closing tag.

BTW, an `alt` attribute is required by standard, however, no browsers will complain about that.

So in your case, you should rewrite all your img tags as follow: **{no '/' at end of img tag and of course no '' closing tag}**

```
 <img name="ImageFileName" src="..." title="" alt="">
```

Plus note tip still from W3C:

> Tip: It is a good practice to specify both the height and width
>   attributes for an image. If these attributes are set, the space
>   required for the image is reserved when the page is loaded. However,
>   without these attributes, the browser does not know the size of the
>   image. The effect will be that the page layout will change during
>   loading (while the images load).

Not sure your problem come from something here, but i'm sure that non-valid html can lead in some problems.

**UPDATE**

Following your update, i see you are using (asp) to render html. You should try this at end of your function:

```
return MvcHtmlString.Create(tag.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
```

PS: i cannot test any asp code.

Comment: I reupdate answer, you should infact try to use "TagRenderMode.StartTag" not "TagRenderMode.SelfClosing" i think. But im afraid, i cannot test asp code.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagrendermode(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I already changed it, yes this is it, I'm testing it now, and hope you soon get 215 new rep!

Comment: You edit my answer with "EndTag". Are you sure it's not "StartTag" instead?

Comment: Rolled back. Now it works in IE8, but not in IE7. I'm checking the HTML source, and I see that the `img` tag is still self-closing. How can I explicitly set the `TagBuilder` to render separate opening and closing tags?

Comment: I have just tested on emulated ie7, ie8, ie9 and that seems to work fine now. Have you think to clear browser's cache?

Comment: "You may award your bounty in 36 minutes." BTW, what emulator do you use? Is there a browser emulator for Google Chrome?

Comment: Thx shimmy! Using Internet Explorer and dev tools (F12), you can change between IE version and quirks mode. This is not possible using chrome as chrome is an auto-updating browser meaning you should always have/use the last stable version available.

Comment: U deserve every bit of it man, thanks for your catch, you're indeed good!

Answer (score 1):

Is the site written in HTML 5?

I recently implemented this into a website that I created and it works perfectly in both IE 8 and IE 7. The website I created was written in HTML 5 and the only thing I changed in order to make the slider work was to change the div tags around the slider to sections and then add the [HTML 5 shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) everything else was stock from the site.

Here's the [site](http://computing.bournemouth.ac.uk/i7747061/assignment2/index.html) I created that works, so hopefully this might help you too

(Don't have 50 rep so can't post this as a comment)

Comment: :( The issue still persists. I added the html5shiv to the MainLayout page, was that supposed to work? If you solve this issue, you'll get more than 50 rep (It's 65 I think)...

Comment: I also changed the divs surrounding the slider to sections using html5 tags