# Make HTML5 & CSS3 website compatible with old browsers?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4, cross-browser

So I created a website in ASP.NET MVC (HTML5 & CSS3).

Now, the page renders awfully in IE ≤ 8, the colors the mouse hovers doesn't work properly, and I'm also facing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15154704/75500) issue.

So, was it a bad idea to adopt HTML5 & CSS3?

From you POV, if you were standing in my situation how would you downgrade the website so it's compatible in at least IE6?

Of course I'm looking for the quickest most-reliable way...

Comment: Yes. It was a bad idea. If only it was possible to develop an HTML5 + CSS3 app for IE6 :( That'd make me _so_ happy

Comment: If you're using certain features in HTML5/CSS3, it may be very tricky (or in some cases impossible) to make your website IE6 compatible

Comment: There is no magic trick that makes your HTML5/CSS3 website "compatible" with IE6-8. First off you have to consider what you're willing to sacrifice while doing graceful degradation. Transitions, rounded corners and gradients are usually sacrificed to provide a faster loading - current hacks like CSS3 Pie are heavy for users of such ancient browsers IMO. Now if you're relying on HTML5 APIs (webgl, canvas, XHR2, File API etc) you will have a hard time making it fallbackable. As your question is too broad I hope you understand that there is no single answer for this and it may end up closed.

Comment: totally agree with @fabriciomatte, without code to look at, hard to diagnose. have you done anything for < ie10? like, html5shiv.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do it would be graceful degradation creating alternate styles for elements that are not supported using modernizr

http://modernizr.com/

You would need to create a test profile for features that are required and modernizr would add tags to those that arnt supported.   the  you just need to create a simple style to make it "work".

```
.glowy { /* ghosted letters */
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
.no-textshadow {
    color: black;
}
```

You have to weight both sides. You can't create a modern site with IE6 in mind and at the same time you can't just ignore it (maybe you can). But you can't be stuck in 1996 either.

This solution allows you to use the newest features while keeping the site usable for grannies.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. The website world great on Chrome and IE but those grannies are moaning. I'm pretty new to web development (I used to do desktop or server side apps). I wanted to know how I can make the website (even lacking some goodies) load somehow in Renaissance browsers investing as less effort as possible.